# Regex Expression for extracting potion of URL

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I construct a regex expression so that it would only match if URL has "loc" parameter.

Right now with the following expression, it's matching not just "loc" but also other parameter names ending in loc.

```
var reg = new RegExp("(?:http)://(.*loc=)|(?:&.*)$");   

var url = "http://www.example.com/access/alternative_alternatif.action?teng=1234.pdf&amp;tfra=1234.pdf&amp;l=eng&amp;aloc=1234.pdf"; //this match even though its "aloc".   

var myparse = url.replace(reg,''); //Output = 1234.pdf
```

I tried adding semicolon just before loc but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var reg = new RegExp("(?:http)://(.;*loc=)|(?:&.*)$");
```

Edit : I have tried all the suggestions, unfortunately they all match url with "*loc" parameter not just "loc"

Comment: Those `&amp;` separators don't belong there - the only separator should be a single `&`, or `?` if it's the first parameter.

Comment: Try with `(.*[&?]loc=)` instead of `(.*loc=)`.

Comment: Your URL is HTML encoded, that's a problem. You should only HTML encode URLs if you're going to put them in HTML. Can you show us the code that produces this code?

Comment: @Halcyon : Those URLs are from CSV files, so I'm not generating anyone of those.

Comment: Are all URLs HTML encoded, or only some of them?

Comment: They are hundreds of them. But all those I checked, they are all encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Get the matched group from index 1

```
(?:&amp;|&|\?)\bloc=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uU0kC7/4)

Sample code:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/access/alternative_alternatif.action?teng=1234.pdf&amp;tfra=1234.pdf&amp;l=eng&amp;aloc=1234.pdf";
var found = url.match(/(?:&amp;|&|\\?)\bloc=(.*?)(?:&|$)/);
```

Note: check for undefined/null and size.

Comment: I tried it but it still matches parameter end with loc. Not just loc

Answer (score 0):

Just the regex:

```
(http\S*;loc\S*)"
```

This will match any url with ";loc" in it.
What would you expect before the loc in your match? I mean is there a character or something else that is always before the "loc"?

Comment: what about if `loc` is fist parameter?

Comment: `(http\S*(;|/|\?)loc\S*)"` OR `(http\S*\bloc\S*)"`